# The stem of my Norfolk Pine Tree

Tags: trees, houseplants, leaves

Can anyone tell me how I can save my Norfolk Pine Tree? The stem is turning brown and the pines turn hard and tan and ends up falling off[image].

Answer (score 2):

If (as it seems from the picture) this is limited to the lower stem, that's fairly normal as the branches shade it out and the needles become unproductive and are thus shed by the plant.

My NFIP also dropped entire lower branches as it grew and shaded them out. Providing more light from the side and/or pruning to limit shading might help to reduce that, if desired.

Personally, I let mine go and have never had the urge to replace it. Successfully maintaining "pyramidal green to the bottom" form is challenging, to put it mildly. Having a cute tree in a pot turned out not to be enough reward for the challenge in my books.

Answer (score 2):

These trees grow on high mountain slopes on Pacific islands and expect high light and high humidity and good air movement.

Indoors it is hard to provide all three of those and the result is the browning of needles on the stems.

Underwatering results in brown tips on the new growth or accelerated dropping of older branches.

As Ecnerwal says, these trees are picky about their environment.