# Norfolk Island Pine w/new growth at base but has dropped 75% of its branches-what’s wrong with it?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, tree-care

Approximately 8 yo Norfolk Island Pine. Has been in the sunroom with good sunlight all of its life and done well and put out new growth every year. Humidity is about 44-55%. Water weekly. Late March it began dropping entire branches (lower to start) and some turned brown (sunburn?) but didn’t drop like the healthy green ones. Have new growth at the base of the plant but no branches on one trunk and very few on the others. Is she too far gone? Help ….
[image]

Comment: See https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/63526/6806